# Index of the spiral and saddle fixed points

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> One of the way to show that spiral has index 1 is using the deformation argument: 
>   Suppose that 
>   $$A=\begin{bmatrix} a  & b \\c &  d \end{bmatrix} \in \mathbb R^{2×2},$$ and the origin is a spiral, i.e. $ad-bc > \frac{(a+d)^2}{4}$, or equivalently $(a-d)^2<-4bc$. The strategy is to continuously deform the matrix so that the attractor/repeller becomes a node, and note that the index of the fixed point changes continuously, and therefore not at all. 
>   Case 1: $a\neq 0:$ Let 
>   $$A_t=\begin{bmatrix} a(t+1)  & b \\c &  \frac{d}{t+1} \end{bmatrix} \in \mathbb R^{2×2}$$
>   for $t\geq 0$.Then $A_0=A$, and as t rises, the determinant remains fixed, but eventually $((t+1)a−\frac{d}{(t+1)})^2<−4bc$ can no longer be true. 
>   Case 2: $a = 0$ (similarly for $d=0$): 
>   $$A_t=\begin{bmatrix} 0  & b \\c &  d+t \end{bmatrix} \in \mathbb R^{2×2},$$
>   
>   Then $A_0=A$, and as $t$ rises, the determinant remains fixed, but eventually $(0−(d+t))2<−4bc$ can no longer hold. 
>   Now note that as $t$ rises, the origin turns from a spiral into a node. The index changes continuously and therefore not at all. If it is $1$ for a node, it must be $1$ for a spiral.

My question is why can the same sort of argument not be used to show that  a saddle has index 1? (a saddle has index −1)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To see what is going on, plot the trace  $T = a+d$ and the determinant $D = ad - bc$ in a coordinate system.

All equilibria with index +1 are in the plane $D > 0$. This includes all stable and unstable nodes and all stable and unstable spirals. They can be connected with a homotopy argument while staying in this half plane.

All equilibria with index -1 are in the plane $D < 0$. These are all the saddle points.

If you want to connect a system where the equilibrium is a node or a spiral to a system where the equilibrium is a saddle via homotopy, you must cross the line $D = 0$, which is where the index switches.